# Give same random value to the random.seed() until a certain condition is met

Tags: django, python-3.x, random

```
def get_unanswered_questions(self, quiz,answers,correct_answers,lev):

    answered_questions = self.quiz_answers \
        .filter(answer__question__quiz=quiz) \
        .values_list('answer__question__pk', flat=True)
    answerss=list(answers)
    correct_answerss=list(correct_answers)
    list_of_ids= list(quiz.questions.values_list('id', flat=True))

    if len(answerss)==0:
          global rand_num
          rand_num=randint(0,1000)

    random.seed(rand_num)
    random.shuffle(list_of_ids)
    clauses = ' '.join(['WHEN id=%s THEN %s' % (pk, i) for i, pk in 
                 enumerate(list_of_ids)])
    ordering = 'CASE %s END' % clauses
    questions = quiz.questions.filter(pk__in=list_of_ids).exclude(pk__in=answered_questions).extra(select={'ordering': ordering }, order_by=('ordering', ))
```

I don't know the proper way of doing it. I need to generate a random number when the **len(answerss)=0** and pass that same number to the random seed value so that the order of questions remain same for each execution of **get_unanswered_questions**
 I need to generate random questions only once the quiz has started and get questions in order of that random ordering
until it gets to another condition when **len(answerss)==0** again.

> I'm getting random numbers for each multiple execution  of the function **get_unanswered_questions**
>   Is there any way of doing it?

Comment: Whats wrong with the code you posted? What is your result and what is the expected result. Its difficult to use _this_ code to do anything, we do not have your database. You might want to simplyfy it with some fixed q/a based on lists to create a better [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Store the list you queried, if your method is called again either return the stored list (if still answers available) or draw new ones. You need to remove answered Q from your list in addition to storing the answer DB side. This is not really a random problem, but a controlflow problem and for that the code is a) too few and b) its not really a good question for SO